# Edit Update Reminder Setup by API

Tags: api, java

Is this possible to edit values of Checkboxes:

```
Update Reminder Setup:
- Enable Update Reminders for My Organization 
- Automatically Activate Reminders for Users with Direct Reports
```

by some API, if I would want to write some app eg. in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change some settings via the Metadata API, but "Enable Update Reminders" is one that isn't supported.

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm?search_text=update%20reminders

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as of Sept. 2021, it turns out you can.

Salesforce's documentation isn't very clear on this. You can't edit the update reminder entries themselves, but you CAN turn update reminders on and off.
The relevant settings are in settings/Opportunity.settings-meta.xml:

```
<autoActivateNewReminders>true</autoActivateNewReminders>
<enableUpdateReminders>true</enableUpdateReminders>
```

control the 2 checkboxes you are referring to.